# In Rails, how to have an /admin section, and then controllers within the admin section?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to have a /admin section in my application, and have routes within this /admin section like:

www.example.com/admin/   (only certain users have acess to this section)

then have controllers in this section like:

```
/admin/users/{add, new, etc}
```

What are my options for something like this? (using rails 3)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Do something like this in your routes.rb:

```
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users
  end
```

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html for more detail.

Then in each admin controller you'll need a before_filter:

```
before_filter :authorized?
def authorized?
    #check if authorized here.
end
```

Answer (score 44):

I prefer to do something similar to Todd's answer but slightly different. Rather than adding the before_filter to each controller related to Admin stuff I prefer to create an AdminController that all controllers related to admin actions can inherit from:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end

# app/controllers/admin_controller.rb
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorized?
  private
  def authorized?
    unless current_user.has_role? :admin
      flash[:error] = "You are not authorized to view that page."
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end

# app/controllers/admin/users_controller.rb
class Admin::UsersController < AdminController
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 9):

As Todd mentioned, you want to add a namespaced route:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :users
end
```

You also need to put your controllers, views, etc in subfolders of each of these sections called "admin/".  If you're generating this from scratch, it's easy:

```
rails g controller admin/users
```

This may seem pretty complicated, but I have an article that walks through all of this, with a sample rails 3 app you can download to play around with it:

[Routing in Ruby on Rails 3](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/02/routing-in-ruby-on-rails-3/)

Answer (score 6):

> Then in each admin controller you'll need a before_filter:
>
> ```
> before_filter :authorized?
> def authorized?
>   #check if authorized here.
> end
> ```

I think it's better if he puts this code into a main AdminController which inherits from ApplicationController, then each admin controller will inherits from this AdminController.

About Rails3, [here](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/) is a good article about routes

Answer (score 3):

Obviously what Todd said is correct. However if you're a fan of additional security through obscurity, you can also keep your `new_admin_user` url helpers and `Admin::` namespaced controllers, but provide a less widely-used public url path with the following:

```
scope  :module => "admin", :as => 'admin', :path => 'xyz' do
 resources :user
end
```

A `rake route` with that setup will show routes along these lines:

```
new_admin_user GET  /xyz/users/new(.:format)  {:controller=>"admin/users", :action=>"new"}
```

I suppose the only actor this would thwart is an unsophisticated attacker who's crawled and compiled a bunch of Rails sites that provide system access at `admin/`, but I don't see any harm in daring to be different with your admin console paths really.

Answer (score 2):

```
application_controller.rb   
before_filter :if_namespace_is_admin?

def if_name_space_is_admin?
    #now you should check to see if the namespace is from admin
    #now you need namespaces because ruby ns confuse the f'out of me
end
```