# How to use scaffolding to create a parallel admin interface? Rails wants to overwrite my controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffolding

I'd like to use rails scaffolding to create an /admin section. I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331686/in-rails-how-to-have-an-admin-section-and-then-controllers-within-the-admin-s), but it's not explained how you would do so while making use of  Rails scaffolds.

I've looked at all of the scaffold_controller options and none of them seems to specify how to put them in folders other than /controllers when creating new scaffolds.

I attemped: `rails g scaffold_controllers admin/mymodels` along with the appropriate routing, but then all of my model references were to `Admin::MyModel`, not `MyModel`. Deleting `Admin::` seemed to have no effect.

Finally, I didn't mention that I already have written a controller or two for the user-facing portion of my app. Does defining MymodelController elsewhere create problems? Do I need to use scaffolds to create the files, and then rename the controllers to something like `AdminMymodel` ?

Note: I'm using Rails 3.1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ryan Bate's Nifty Generators. Add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem "nifty-generators"
```

then run:

```
rails g nifty:scaffold Admin::MyModels name:string content:text
```

This will create everything a normal scaffold would do with the controllers and views in an 'admin' namespace, but the model not in namespace.